Math notation ideal
I have been playing with Math notation thinking if it was possible to simplify our current notation. First I thought that it would be unnecessary to use any base system besides the Unary numeral system (and it would almost force us to use the prime numbers). Then addition would be only the concatenation of numbers (using the plus sign the the equal sign):
111 + 1111 = 1111111
Then all the rest basic operations could be created symplifiying addition and using algebra:
$A$ meaning the quantity/number of $a$s (First symbol = Quantity of the second symbol)
$\ A \cdot a = a + a + a + \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt} + a $
$ A \cdot \cdot  a = a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt} \cdot a $
$ A \cdot \cdot \cdot a = a \cdot \cdot a \cdot \cdot a  \cdot \cdot a  \cdot \cdot \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt}  \cdot \cdot a $
$\vdots$
Now the opposite operations would be:
$ x - y = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow z + y = x $ (What is the number $z$, so that $z$ plus $y$ equals $x$)
$ A \hspace{3pt} \alpha \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow z \cdot a = A $
$ A \hspace{3pt} \alpha \alpha \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow z \cdot \cdot a = A $
$ A \hspace{3pt} \alpha \alpha \alpha \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow z \cdot \cdot \cdot a = A $
$\vdots$
And:
$ A \hspace{3pt} \beta \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow a \cdot z = A $
$ A \hspace{3pt} \beta \beta \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow a \cdot \cdot z = A $
$ A \hspace{3pt} \beta \beta \beta \hspace{3pt} a = z  \hspace{10pt} $
$ z \rightarrow a \cdot \cdot \cdot z = A $
$\vdots$
Some examples:
$ 111 + 11 = 11111 $
$ 111 - 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow z + 11 = 111 \hspace{10pt} \therefore z = 1 $
$\quad $
$ 111 \cdot 11 = 11 + 11 + 11 = 111111 $
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \alpha \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow z \cdot 11 = 111  \hspace{10pt} (3 \div 2 = 1.5)$
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \beta \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow 11 \cdot z = 111  \hspace{10pt} (3 \div 2 = 1.5)$
$\quad$
$ 111 \cdot \cdot 11 = 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 = (11 \cdot 11) \cdot 11 = 1111 \cdot 11 = 11 + 11 + 11 + 11 = 11111111  \hspace{10pt} (2^3 = 8)$
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \alpha \alpha \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow z \cdot \cdot 11 = 111  \hspace{10pt} (log_2(3) = z)$
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \beta \beta \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow 11 \cdot z = 111  \hspace{10pt} (z^2 = 3 \hspace{5pt} \therefore z = \sqrt{3}) $
$\quad$
$ 111 \cdot \cdot \cdot 11 = 11 \cdot \cdot 11 \cdot \cdot 11 = (11 \cdot \cdot 11) \cdot \cdot 11 = 1111 \cdot \cdot 11 = 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 = ((11 \cdot 11)\cdot 11) \cdot 11 = (1111 \cdot 11) \cdot 11 = 11111111 \cdot 11 = 1111111111111111 $
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \alpha \alpha \alpha \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow z \cdot \cdot \cdot 11 = 111 \hspace{10pt}$ (How many 2s raised to the power of 2s you need, so that it is equal to 3? $\hspace{10pt} 1<z<2 $)
$ 111 \hspace{3pt} \beta \beta \beta \hspace{3pt} 11 = z \hspace{10pt} z \rightarrow 11 \cdot \cdot \cdot z = 111 \hspace{10pt} (z^z = 3)$
$\quad$
I have been since the idea of an ideal notation of math, very interested in History of Math and Notation. And since there is a lot irregular things in our notation, my question is: Could an ideal notation exist? (Following this pattern: $thing1$ + relation-between-thing1-and-thing2 + $thing2$ + relation-between-thing1-thing2-and-(evaluation-of-thing1-and-thing2) + evaluation-of-thing1-and-thing2 )
What are the other standard, if any, notation of math in the world?
Sorry for the LaTex, I am still learning how to use it.
Edit:Trying to implement the summation and the capital-pi lead me to change somethings in the basic operations in order to not add more symbols for the operators. I first thought of using $ A \hspace{3pt} \sigma \hspace{3pt} f(x) = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + ... + f(A)$ and the $\varsigma$ for the multiplication, $\varsigma \varsigma$ exponentiation..., but if we used this method it would change all the pattern that was used before, so $ A \hspace{3pt} \sigma \hspace{3pt} f(x) $ would be equal to $ f(x)_1 + f(x)_2 + f(x)_3 + ... + f(x)_A $
In order to have the summation and the capital-pi we can make these changes:
$ A \cdot f(x) = f(1) + f(11) + f(111) + ... + f(A) $
$ A \cdot \cdot f(x) = f(1) \cdot f(11) \cdot f(111) \cdot \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt} \cdot f(A) $
$ A \cdot \cdot \cdot f(x) = f(1) \cdot \cdot f(11) \cdot \cdot f(111) \cdot \cdot \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt} \cdot \cdot f(A) $
And so on.
$$ \sum_{1}^{A}2k+1 = A \cdot (2x+1) $$ $\hspace{6cm} $(Which is different from $ A \cdot 3$ )
$$ \prod_{1}^{A} k = A \cdot \cdot x $$

Tally marks are the oldest system of enumeration and predate written language by thousands of years. The problem is that if you use up too much room when writing large numbers so a unary base is impractical. In most modern math discourse we avoid choosing a base whenever possible since it can artificially complicate the problem. However it occasionally be useful to pick one when working on certain problems, especially binary.

Multiplying 12 and 15 is easy. Multiplying $||||||||||||$ and $|||||||||||||||$ is less so. Relatedly, which is bigger, $$|||||||||||||||||||||||||| \quad\mbox{or}\quad |||||||||||||||||||||||||?$$

@NoahSchweber: Still easy. Just super tedious. Writing it tedious too.

In general, my feeling is that this sort of exercise may be interesting foundationally, but it's not really ideal from a practical perspective.

I see that starting with a conventional dot for multiplication ($A\cdot a$), you duplicated the dot in $A \cdot \cdot  a$ to represent exponentiation, which we would conventionally write $a^A$. This is reminiscent of the way the designers of FORTRAN, who used * for multiplication (since the IBM keypunch had neither "$\cdot$" nor "$\times$") duplicated the * for exponentiation -- although they kept the exponent of $X^Y$ on the right, writing X**Y where your notation would be $Y\cdot\cdot X$. You've also rediscovered tetration in $A\cdot\cdot\cdot a$.

I have to say, though, that the "$\cdot \cdot \cdot$" on the left-hand side of $A \cdot \cdot \cdot a = a \cdot \cdot a \cdot \cdot a  \cdot \cdot a  \cdot \cdot \hspace{3pt} \cdots \hspace{3pt}  \cdot \cdot a$ looks an awful lot like the "$\cdots$" on the right-hand side; and we'd all have to learn that $A\cdots a$ no longer means what it already means today.

@NoahSchweber Yeah. I actually was using the Base 10 when writing on paper and thought that would be interesting if we used more and were more attentive to the primes. But even so, big numbers would still be hard to differentiate. Maybe staying with the normal base is the most efficient.

@DavidK Yes, haha. I've had a lot of problems to understand even what I was writing on paper. I have tried using +++, but I thought it would create a problem with the rule that "the first number represents the quantity of the second number" and what 11 + 111 would mean (we have [2 plus 3] which would be to equal  [3 (0 plusses) 3)]. So I opt to the dot/multiplication sign.

@PageSteiner concatenation is still studied with strings in computer science. So there is some value in the operation itself even if it's not ideal for numerical computations. Binary allows some clever operations on strings which turn into mathematical operations. Quake's famous fast inverse squareroot algorithm is one such example.

The Base system could be easily changed and the symbols and the notation-system for the operations still preserved. I began to think now more about the regularity of the notation and the minimal number of symbols used for creating an operation (I don't know a notation that has a symbol for $A \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot a$). So another question could be: What is the notation that uses the minimal number of symbols to represent the same number of operations?

Wait until you find out that $0$ is not representable

And if you really want to go that far you can use the Von Newmann ordinals: $ 0 = \emptyset, 1 = {\emptyset}, 2 = {0,1} = {\emptyset,{\emptyset}}, 3 = {0,1,2} = ...$

@ioveri Oh, because of the base 1. But we could just write (x - x) or even assign the symbol 0 to (x - x) (or use another base). But I think it would break the pattern that was created. And why create a symbol that will only be used for one thing/concept. My first thought wasn't about practicality.

"a symbol for $A \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot a$": see Knuth up-arrow notation. (I think this validates your idea of repeating a symbol to express the next higher operation. The main difference is that Knuth first introduced the symbol for exponentiation rather than multiplication.)

@DavidK I see. It makes sense to start with the exponentiation since its form breaks the regularity of " A symbol a symbol evaluation " that was used for addition, subtraction and multiplication.

using + for a non commutative operation is not indicated

@Noah Schweber: I just saw this question (was edited 5 minutes ago) -- it must not have been on any of the "front page questions" for me in the past 19 hours. Anyway, I didn't realize this was 19 hours old initially and was mentally formulating a comment that wound up being very similar to your comment, which I saw a few moments later when I got to the end of the question and started looking at the comments (and at that point I realized this was not a very recently asked question). So +1 for your comment, for what it's worth!
